# Input in if else not looping back?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a program that gets the prime factors of a number, as well as checks if it is prime or not, based on the user's command. I'm running into an issue where the if-else statement does not loop back, meaning that after the output is given, the user is prompted to give another command. After the user gives the command, the program ends.

```
  command = input("Enter a command (factor, isprime, end): ")
  command = command.lower()

  if command != "factor" and command != "isprime" and command != "end":
    print("Command", command,"not recognized. Try again!")
    command = input("Enter a command (factor, isprime, end): ")
    command = command.lower()

  elif command == "factor":
    num =  int(input("Enter an integer > 1: "))
    primeFactorsOf(num)
    print("")
    command = input("Enter a command (factor, isprime, end): ")
    command = command.lower()

  elif command == "isprime":
    num =  int(input("Enter an integer > 1: "))
    findPrime(num)
    print("")
    command = input("Enter a command (factor, isprime, end): ")
    command = command.lower()

  elif command == "end":
    print("Thanks for using our service! Goodbye.")
```

Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: Just one thing tho, there isn't a function that's called primeFactorsOf() or findPrime() are you later going to define those function?

Comment: There is no need to compare to all the commands at the start of your `if..elif` block.  Just add the final `else:` clause, and it will execute if none of the previous commands matched.

Comment: Well, yes; it doesn't loop because there is no loop.

Answer (score 1):

You added some extra unneeded comparisons.  The following accomplishes the same logic, and would actually make adding additional commands easier:

```
while True:
    command = input("Enter a command (factor, isprime, end): ")
    command = command.lower()

    if command == "factor":
        num = int(input("Enter an integer > 1: "))
        primeFactorsOf(num)
        print("")

    elif command == "isprime":
        num =  int(input("Enter an integer > 1: "))
        findPrime(num)
        print("")

    elif command == "end":
        print("Thanks for using our service! Goodbye.")
        break # Explicitly "break" out of the loop.

    else:
        print("Command", command,"not recognized. Try again!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of loops!

```
while True:
  command = input("Enter a command (factor, isprime, end): ")
  command = command.lower()

  if command != "factor" and command != "isprime" and command != "end":
    print("Command", command,"not recognized. Try again!")

  elif command == "factor":
    num = int(input("Enter an integer > 1: "))
    primeFactorsOf(num)
    print("")

  elif command == "isprime":
    num =  int(input("Enter an integer > 1: "))
    findPrime(num)
    print("")

  elif command == "end":
    print("Thanks for using our service! Goodbye.")
    break # Explicitly "break" out of the loop.
```

Comment: Why do you need to check if command is not equal to the three values, wouldn't else take care of it by default?

Comment: @JoeFerndz: That's completely reasonable. I was attempting to change their code as little as possible

Answer (score 0):

Oh, right now your program don't loop back to the begining after you asked for another command. Using a while loop can easily solve the problem.

```
while True:
    command = input("Enter a command (factor, isprime, end): ")
    command = command.lower()

    if command != "factor" and command != "isprime" and command != "end":
        print("Command", command,"not recognized. Try again!")

    elif command == "factor":
        num =  int(input("Enter an integer > 1: "))
        # primeFactorsOf(num)
        print("")


    elif command == "isprime":
        num =  int(input("Enter an integer > 1: "))
        # findPrime(num)
        print("")

    elif command == "end":
        print("Thanks for using our service! Goodbye.")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `while True`. and make an `else:` since the user might give an invalid input. (By the way use `f strings`). By the way, You added some extra unneeded comparisons so I fixed it:

```
while True: # this loops forever.
    command = input("Enter a command (factor, isprime, end): ")
    command = command.lower()

    if command == "factor":
        num = int(input("Enter an integer > 1: "))
        primeFactorsOf(num)
        print("")

    elif command == "isprime":
        num =  int(input("Enter an integer > 1: "))
        findPrime(num)
        print("")

    elif command == "end":
        print("Thanks for using our service! Goodbye.")
        break # Explicitly "break" out of the loop. if you don't it'll keep looping.

    else:
        print(f"Command {command} not recognized. Try again!")
```